# secure-file-priv error while importing csv file in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, load-data-infile, mysqlimport

I am trying to import csv file in sql, please find the below code:

LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\Assignment\Auto.csv' INTO TABLE assignments.`Auto`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;

Its giving me the error:

Error Code: 1290. The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement    0.016 sec

I then tried with keyword LOCAL(as mentioned in some of the solutions) and it gave me error:

Error Code: 1148. The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version   0.000 sec

As i found many solution to this, so i checked the value of this variable manually in session with command:

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";

the output for this is :

secure_file_priv    C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\

**This is the same location i am using in the load data path above.

I checked the C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini file and it has the below details:

## Secure File Priv.

secure-file-priv="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads"
Can someone please tell me what is the issue here and how can i resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE …` you need to set MySQL Server global variable `local_infile` to true.

```
SET GLOBAL local_infile = true;
```

You need also pass `--local-infle` option to `mysql` command-line client

```
mysql --local-infile -hlocalhost -uroot -p
```

About secure file priv error - does your `Auto.csv` file is on the same machine where MySQL Server is running?

Answer (score 1):

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";
```

This command will show the path, for example

```
C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/
```

Put your file in the same path in uploads
Also check the backslash in both the path. If it is different, change in your code.
I did the two steps and it got resolved in MySQL 8.